# How acess/get/extract the values of POLYGON in a geometry column of Geopandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

How can i get the values of coordinate in a POLYGON in a Geopandas Dataframe?

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file("CAMPOS_PRODUCAO_SIRGASPolygon.shp")
```

I can easy do it for a centroid of my POLYGON

with it:

```
print(campos_shape.centroid.iloc[0].x)
-39.853276865819765
print(type(campos_shape.centroid.iloc[0].x))
<class 'float'>
```

I want a list or numpy array with all point value of lat and lon
contained in POLYGON

So how can i convert a POLYGON to numpy array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, here is one solution
that work for me:

```
def coord_lister(geom):
    coords = list(geom.exterior.coords)
    return (coords)

coordinates_list = your_geopandas_df.geometry.apply(coord_lister)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:
This for example gives you the coordinates of the polygon for the first entry in the shapefile:

```
list(shapefile["geometry"][0].exterior.coords)
```

Comment: Thx, for reply but in this way I'll just filter my dataframe, I want the lat and lon values ​​inside the POLYGON

Comment: Additionally with `shapefile["geometry"][0].interior` you can check whether the polygon has inner coordinates as well.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: No, =( . But it is ok . I find a solution i will plot it here.